# Adding S3 sync step in EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

After performing all the steps, I want to execute the last step to copy S3 data to another bucket.

I didn't find any supported script for running shell commands

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-commandrunner.html

**s3-dist-cp** is supported and I could have used it if it allows me to override target directory data.

I need something like:

```
{
  action_on_failure   = "CONTINUE"
  name                = "copy s3 data"
  hadoop_jar_step     = [{
     args    = ["bash" , "  aws s3 sync s3://bucket1/data s3://bucket2/data"]
     jar = "command-runner.jar"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-launch-custom-jar-cli.html).

From CLI you can use this config bit for the step:

```
Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name="Copy s3 data",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Jar="command-runner.jar",Args=["aws","s3","sync","s3://bucket1/data","s3://bucket2/data"]
```